# How to change value to X-Magento-Vary cookie based on URL parameter?

Tags: magento2.3, cache, cookie

I would like to change the value of the 'X-Magento-Vary' cookie based on URL query string, just like when a customer logs in or store is beeing changed.

*I created a plugin to set a value to the http contexts:*

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
    <plugin name="my_page_cache_variation" type="My\Module\Plugin\Framework\App\Http\ChangeCustomerContext" />
</type>
```

*In the plugin code I have:*

```
 /**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface  $subject
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
 */
public function beforeDispatch(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
)
{
    $code_ref = $request->getParam('url_code');
    if ( $code_ref ) {
        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            Context::CONTEXT_GROUP,
            $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId(),
            0
        );
    }
}
```

**But the 'X-Magento-Vary' is not changing as expected.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need create before plugin on `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context:getVaryString()`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context">
    <plugin name="my_page_cache_variation" 
type="My\Module\Plugin\Framework\App\Http\ChangeCustomerContext" />
</type>
```

> Plugin:

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin\Framework\App\Http;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;

class ChangeCustomerContext {

    /**
     * @param Context  $subject
     *
     * @return void.
     */
    public function beforeGetVaryString(Context $subject)
    {
       $code = $request->getParam('url_code');
        if ($code) {
            $subject->setValue(
                Context::CONTEXT_GROUP,
                $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId(),
                0
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy!
It's very strange, because I tryed it before and it didnt work for me... and now it did.